# clarification on vim pattern matching

Tags: regex, vim

I want to convert the 5 space indentation in a python file to 4 space indentation. I want the command to do the following

remove a single space in all the lines which starts with a space followed by characters.

I issued the command  **%s/^\ [a-zA-Z]*//** which seems to work. Later i figured out that the command should actually be

remove a single space in all the lines which starts with a space followed by **any number of spaces** followed by characters.

However still i am not able to figure out how the command(above) is working. It should basically report error for the following stating pattern not found but still it works.

```
class H:
     def __init__():
         hell()
```

Comment: Can't you substitute every 5 spaces by 4 spaces ?

Comment: The command i issued does that, later i figured that it should not be doing that. i dont know why it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working because `*` means "match zero or more of the previous atom".  In your case, it's matching zero.  You probably wanted to use `\+` instead which means "match one or more of the previous atom".

In actuality, you could have just dropped the `*` entirely because just a space followed by a single character would have matched what you were *originally* searching for.  There are better regular expressions for what you're trying to accomplish, but that's not what you're asking here.

Edit (clarification):

Your regex as it stands (`^\ [a-zA-Z]*`) translates to:

- `^`: From the start of the line
- `\`: Match a space
- `[a-zA-Z]`: Followed by a letter
- `*`: Zero or more times (of the previous atom - a letter)

Comment: Which means it matches line 2 and 3(as shown in my previous post). But why does it removes a single space in the line 2 and 3.

Comment: Try the following: `:set hlsearch`, then `/^\ [a-zA-Z]*`.  This will show you what your regular expression is matching, and also what your substitute command is removing.  Maybe that will help explain my answer.

Comment: @Randy Morris:- I got the following error: E486: Pattern not found: ^\[a-zA-Z]

Comment: Are you using the same code snippet from above?  With that exact snippet and my exact search from above, I get the first space on lines 2 and 3 highlighted.

Comment: @Randy Morris:- I am using the same code snippet and still i am not able to higlights.

Comment: @RandyMorris:- what version of vim you are using, on which operating system.

Comment: Also, you don't need to escape the space with a `\`, that caused me a bit of confusion for a second.  It seems vim doesn't care if you do or not though.

Comment: sorry it was a typo in the search pattern , instead of issuing command /^\ [a-zA-Z]* i typed /^\ [a-zA-Z]. Missed out the *